# For testing purposes, can you allow mixed content in browsers?

Tags: .net, ajax, http, https

I'm using a public api from another company which has a sandbox address that ONLY serves http requests (no https available).

In my development environment I want to use this sandbox version from my https page, can I enable my browser to accept mixed content to run manual tests?

If not, how can I work around this issue? Would it be a correct approach to have my server side code handle this call instead of ajax, I assume this is a browser problem and I could just create an http request in .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, this is a browser feature. One possible solution which you've already mentioned is to make the call from the server-side; the downside to this is the unnecessary traffic now going to your web servers since they're now acting as a proxy.

Depending on the browser, you may be able to enable the http calls (ex. chrome will have a shield in the URL bar which when you click on it will allow you to load unsafe scripts).

You could also configure your web app to run over http in the development environment so that the requests aren't blocked. I'd suggest this route, along with a follow up email to whatever company this is to request that they enable https for their sandbox APIs.